# Minimum number of elements in array which gives same OR value as that of entire array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of n elements. Question is to find minimum number of elements from the array which will result in same OR as original array.

Eg `arr[] = {1,2,3,4,6}`. OR of all the values in the array gives **7**.
If we consider only elements **6,1** and OR it we get **7**. So the answer is **2**.

My approach is to construct a binary tree of 0s and 1s, with 0 forming the left child and 1 forming right child.

Fetch the final answer(i.e 7) traverse the tree and find the closest number which covers almost all bits of 7. Kind of struck after this first step.

Can anyone please give a hint on how to proceed with next iterations.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach. Yes its binary operation.

Comment: Is there any constraints? how large is `n`? how large is each element in the array?

Comment: @PhamTrung You can consider the constraint as 100,000

Comment: BTW the set cover problem is NP hard, and I believe it remains hard even if the universe size is bounded (e.g., the 32 or 64 bits of an integer). This seems hopeless for `n = 100,000`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: DP solution, `O*(2^|U|)` time where `U` is the universe of bit positions you care about: https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~malcin/dydaktyka/2012-13/fpt/fpt_04_FSC-kociumaka.pdf

Comment: The thought of this draws parallels with prime number hunting with  sieve of Eratosthenes

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Set Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which is NP-hard. The `1` bits in the OR-ed array are the set being covered and the numbers in the array map subsets,  i.e. each number represents the subset of ones which are set in its binary representation.

The greedy algorithm produces log(N) approximation ratio. Proof: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f12/lectures/lect1106.pdf

Comment: It's NP hard, so every known algorithm is exponential. Adding the simple approximation one.

Comment: Dowgird  Thanks for the info. Can you suggest what is the approach for the above problem

Answer (score 0):

Some insights that will aid in optimization.

1. Any number that is 'fully masked' /eclipsed by another, with an OR operation that e.g. a | b == b is true, then a is useless to the solution.
2. The number of set binary bits matter, the more bits set, the more
   likely it's going to be a part of the final solution.
3. numbers with bits in common with many others are unlikely to be in the
   solution.

So from this, I *think* the direction to go in, is to count the number of unique bits in each number, that don't appear on any of the others. IF you find one, That is going to be in the solution. if not, pick the bit with the smallest amount of numbers that have it set, and split the problem up recursively.

Once you narrow the problem down to a single number for a single bit, you can then calculate the amount of unique bits in each of the others, that are different then the number already found to be in the solution.

Doing this multiple times, recursively should end you up with the answer.

How to optimize it further I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can only be solved by trying every possible combination and selecting (one of), the smallest combinations of integers with the same 'or' value as all the values 'or'd together.

That blows up for larger sets of integers.

You could get a good result by using my [greedy algorithm](http://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2013/05/greedy-ranking-algorithm-in-python.html).
If the numbers (mapping to tests), are represented by indications of which bits are set in their binary representation (mapping to test coverage), then the greedy algorithm will give a subset of integers that cover all possible bits, that is usually quite small.